# Cannot create SustainSys CertificateElement from X509Certificate2 object to update SAML2 configuration in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml-2.0, sustainsys-saml2

I'm working on an ASP.NET SAML2 service provider client based on Sustainsys.Saml2.HttpModule. In general Sustainsys seems to be a mature library and I had a basic website using SAML2 authentication up and running quickly. However, I run into a problem that is blocking for me. We need to provide the website's configuration in code, not in web.config. That is well possible, except for the SP `<serviceCertificates>` collection. Here we need at least one certificate having a private key, to sign the SP's assertions. In the `CertificateElement` class there are two options to load a certificate:

1. Load from file. That doesn't work, because the SustainSys code lacks the possibility to specify the file's password. A certificate file containing a private key *must* have a password.
2. Load from certificate store. That will in general only work if the website runs as LocalSystem. An IIS application pool running as a regular user cannot access the private key, not even in the CurrentUser/My store, unless the Load User Profile setting of the application pool is set. And you cannot in general control that in a hosted environment.

The easiest fix of the issue would be to have a third option, where the `CertificateElement` loads its certificate from an `X509Certificate2` object.

**My question: is there another solution? Am I overlooking something? I would prefer to *not* edit the library code.**

[Edit]
Using the answer of @anders-abel, my complicated library change is not required at all (and I am glad!). I removed that code outline.

Only two things left:

1. Before application start, I register the SustainSys HttpModule and one of my own. To initialize SustainSys, I write a temp application.config file and remove it again. Now the ServiceCertificates node is no longer added in that config.

```c
    string configFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), configFileName);
    StringBuilder sb = GetTextResource("sustainsys.config");
    if (sb != null)
    {
      sb.Replace("$entityId", entityId);
      //sb.Replace("$serviceCertificate", SigningCertificate.ToBase64String());
      sb.Replace("$identityProviders", GetIdentityProvidersList());
      File.WriteAllText(configFilePath, sb.ToString());
      SustainsysSaml2Section.Configuration 
        = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(
            new ExeConfigurationFileMap() { ExeConfigFilename = configFilePath },
            ConfigurationUserLevel.None, true);
      File.Delete(configFilePath);
      return true;
    }
```

2. To use Anders Abel's solution, I have to wait until the SustainSys module is initialized. I add the service certificate in my own HttpModule initn, that is called after SustainSys's Init. Because that is done more than once, I only add the certifcate if `ServiceCertificates.Count == 0`.

```c
/// <summary>
/// Initializes the Decos.Saml2 HttpModule.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
  _usingIntegratedPipeline = HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline;
  context.BeginRequest += OnBeginRequest;
  if (Enabled)
  {
    if (Saml2AuthenticationModule.Options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Count == 0)
    {
      Saml2AuthenticationModule.Options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates
        .Add(ConfigSustainSys.SigningCertificate);
    }
    Saml2AuthenticationModule.Options.Notifications.Unsafe
      .TokenValidationParametersCreated
        = (validationParameters, idp, idpResponseXml) =>
      {
        SetBestMatchingNameClaim(validationParameters, idpResponseXml);
      };

    Saml2AuthenticationModule.Options.Notifications
      .AcsCommandResultCreated = (result, response) =>
    {
      // TODO
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `web.config` there is support for specifying the store etc. and the code to load from a store is in the library.

When configuring from code, the idea is that you get an `X509Certificate2` instance by your own code. That could be loading from a store, from file, from database or anything.

Then to use it you register it with the SpOptions:

```
spOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(myX509Certificate2);
```

Or, if you want to define the allowed usage:

```
spOptions.ServiceCertificates.InsertItem(0, new ServiceCertificate
{
  Certificate = myX509Certificate2,
  Use = CertificateUse.Signing
}
```

Comment: t works great. Only one tiny addition: i add the certificate from my own HttpModule, that comes after SustainSys in the pipeline. I noticed that Init is called multiple times and ServiceCertificates.Count was increasing. As I only use 1 certificate, the simple fix was to only add my certificate `if (Saml2AuthenticationModule.Options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Count == 0)`